# Unable to import 365 kb sql files to phpmyadmin on WampServer

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, wamp

It keeps loading while trying to import even small sized sql files to phpmyadmin on WampServer installed on Windows 8. I get following error

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in D:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4\libraries\dbi\mysqli.dbi.lib.php on line 267
```

I have included error log below.

```
[Mon Mar 17 19:03:20.009137 2014] [:error] [pid 5160:tid 1672] [client ::1:55653] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in D:\\wamp\\apps\\phpmyadmin4.0.4\\libraries\\dbi\\mysqli.dbi.lib.php on line 267, referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/import.php
[Mon Mar 17 19:03:20.009137 2014] [:error] [pid 5160:tid 1672] [client ::1:55653] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/import.php
[Mon Mar 17 19:03:20.009137 2014] [:error] [pid 5160:tid 1672] [client ::1:55653] PHP   1. {main}() D:\\wamp\\apps\\phpmyadmin4.0.4\\import.php:0, referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/import.php
[Mon Mar 17 19:03:20.009137 2014] [:error] [pid 5160:tid 1672] [client ::1:55653] PHP   2. ImportSql->doImport() D:\\wamp\\apps\\phpmyadmin4.0.4\\import.php:489, referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/import.php
[Mon Mar 17 19:03:20.009137 2014] [:error] [pid 5160:tid 1672] [client ::1:55653] PHP   3. PMA_importRunQuery() D:\\wamp\\apps\\phpmyadmin4.0.4\\libraries\\plugins\\import\\ImportSql.class.php:414, referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/import.php
[Mon Mar 17 19:03:20.009137 2014] [:error] [pid 5160:tid 1672] [client ::1:55653] PHP   4. PMA_DBI_try_query() D:\\wamp\\apps\\phpmyadmin4.0.4\\libraries\\import.lib.php:158, referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/import.php
[Mon Mar 17 19:03:20.010143 2014] [:error] [pid 5160:tid 1672] [client ::1:55653] PHP   5. PMA_DBI_real_query() D:\\wamp\\apps\\phpmyadmin4.0.4\\libraries\\database_interface.lib.php:192, referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/import.php
[Mon Mar 17 19:09:23.798129 2014] [:error] [pid 5160:tid 1672] [client ::1:55969] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in D:\\wamp\\apps\\phpmyadmin4.0.4\\libraries\\dbi\\mysqli.dbi.lib.php on line 267, referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/import.php
[Mon Mar 17 19:09:23.798129 2014] [:error] [pid 5160:tid 1672] [client ::1:55969] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/import.php
[Mon Mar 17 19:09:23.798129 2014] [:error] [pid 5160:tid 1672] [client ::1:55969] PHP   1. {main}() D:\\wamp\\apps\\phpmyadmin4.0.4\\import.php:0, referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/import.php
[Mon Mar 17 19:09:23.798129 2014] [:error] [pid 5160:tid 1672] [client ::1:55969] PHP   2. ImportSql->doImport() D:\\wamp\\apps\\phpmyadmin4.0.4\\import.php:489, referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/import.php
[Mon Mar 17 19:09:23.798129 2014] [:error] [pid 5160:tid 1672] [client ::1:55969] PHP   3. PMA_importRunQuery() D:\\wamp\\apps\\phpmyadmin4.0.4\\libraries\\plugins\\import\\ImportSql.class.php:414, referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/import.php
[Mon Mar 17 19:09:23.798129 2014] [:error] [pid 5160:tid 1672] [client ::1:55969] PHP   4. PMA_DBI_try_query() D:\\wamp\\apps\\phpmyadmin4.0.4\\libraries\\import.lib.php:158, referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/import.php
[Mon Mar 17 19:09:23.798129 2014] [:error] [pid 5160:tid 1672] [client ::1:55969] PHP   5. PMA_DBI_real_query() D:\\wamp\\apps\\phpmyadmin4.0.4\\libraries\\database_interface.lib.php:192, referer: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/import.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well of course the reason is that phpMyAdmin is a php app and therefore is limited by the `max_execution_time` in php.ini

**Solution 1** is to change your php.ini file and increase the exec time like so

```
max_execution_time = 2000
```

**Solution 2** Would be to just increase the time for the phpMyAdmin app like so

Edit \wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf and add these lines to that file just after the `Alias /phpmyadmin .....` line

```
php_admin_value max_execution_time 2000
php_admin_value max_input_time 2000
```

**Solution 3.** The best solution in my mind for restoring large database dumps is to use the `MySQL Console` as this is not limited in any way and will just run until your backup file is completely processed.

left click wampmanager icon -> MySQL -> MySQL Console
Enter your 'root' password or just hit enter is you have no password on the 'root' userid.

Then enter this command as the `mysql >` prompt

```
source path/to/the/backup/file.sql
```

If you take option 1 or 2 dont forget to set the `max_execution_time` back to no more than 60 seconds. If you ever make the mistake ( and none of us are perfect) of writing an infinite loop in PHP code the PHP code will run for `max_execution_time` before giving an error. This can be very confusing if it runs for 2000/60 = 33.5 minutes before giving you a clue to your error.